# Flex 4.6 with itemrenderer with textinput inside

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

i have a itemrenderer that is contain:

```
<s:TextInput x="10" y="41" width="60" name="txtprice"/>
```

and i want to access to this field from outside.
how can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean with `access to this field from outside`? Please be more specific.

Comment: And **why** do you want to access the TextInput? What do you want to do with it? I'm asking because @SunilD.'s answer is a correct answer to your question as you put it, but I suspect it is not the right solution for your problem. But I don't know for sure because you leave too much information to be guessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<s:List id="list" itemRenderer="com.myDomain.myProject.MyRenderer" />
<s:Button label="click me" click="onButtonClick()"/>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.IVisualElement;

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var myRenderer:CustomItemRenderer = list.dataGroup.getElementAt(0) as CustomItemRenderer;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Since itemRenderers are usually recycled, an itemRenderer is not created for an element that is off screen. That is, if your list has 20 elements, and only the first 10 are visible, `getElementAt()` will return null if you try to get the 11th-20th elements.  If you scroll the element into view, the renderer is created/recycled, and then you can retrieve it.

I seem to recall a better way of dealing with this, but it's not coming to mind.

Note there is another method: `list.dataGroup.getVirtualElementAt()` but this seems to behave the same for me as the non-virtual method.

Finally, be sure to assign the `TextInput` in your renderer an `id`so you can reference it after you retrieve the renderer:

```
<s:TextInput id="txtprice" />
```